# "a room like this justice"?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching The modern family S1 episode 7 studying English. I'm not native speaker, so please understand my poor English skill. I've found like an idiomatic sentence. it is as follows,

> phil : this is the great room, although "great" hardly seems to do a room **like this justice**.

phil is a realtor, and he is looking around a model house with his potential customer.

What i can't figure out is in bold. I think saying that is like "great" doesn't seem to fit with this room(cuz it's way better). and I think the sentence is okay without "like this justice".

so What does "like this justice" mean?

Comment: The writer is saying *a room like this [room]* not *like this justice*.  So - "It hardly *does a room like this [room]* justice."  It means a nice room *like this room* is not adequately described as *great*. It's better than that and calling it *great* does not do it justice (i.e. adequately describe its grandeur).

Comment: You're not parsing the sentence quite correctly. Phil is using the idiom "to do X justice", and is using the phrase "a room like this" for the object X.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic expression is ***to do justice to something/someone***, meaning:

> to treat or show (something or someone) in a way that is as good as it
> should be
>
> - Words could never ***do justice to*** her beauty.
> - The movie does not ***do justice to*** the book.

Now, "to something/someone" can be replaced by a personal pronoun and placed before "justice":

> Just calling the movie “fun” doesn’t ***do it justice***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-justice-to-someone-something))

or

> The photograph I had seen ***didn't do her justice***. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/do-justice))

In your sentence, the word order is slightly confusing, and this is what probably led you to parse it incorrectly. The sentence itself is not grammatically incorrect, but it  is clumsy to insert the object consisting of more than one word between "do" and "justice". I would rather express it in this way:

> This is the great room, although "great" hardly seems ***to do justice to*** a room like this.